# Spring cloud config OAuth2.0 protected server client authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry, spring-cloud-config-client

I am planning to use [jhipster-registry](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry) as spring cloud config server. I have implemented OAuth 2.0 security mechanism for protecting the server.

The problem is, not sure how is a cloud config client (spring boot server with configured with `spring.cloud.config.*`) supposed to authenticate with server protected against with OAuth2.0.

Things I have checked
[Spring Cloud Config OAuth 2.0 Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_oauth_2_0)
[jhipster-regsitry OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry#oauth-20-and-openid-connect)

None of the texts document client side configuration to enable the integration.

I found an unofficial solution [spring-cloud-config-client-oauth2](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-cloud-config-client-oauth2/) but I am afraid to use a custom solution for security.